# Stop OneNote 2013 printing to multiple pages

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2013

As you can see in the image below, whenever I print a multi-paged file to OneNote 2013, for some reason it prints each page to a new page in OneNote instead of all to the one page, driving me insane!  I never had this problem in OneNote 2010 and was wondering if there was a solution to it?

[image: Multiple pages being created for the one document!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this great answer at the [Microsoft site](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-onenote/print-to-onenote-2013-single-page/e9abe737-2581-4d91-9038-5a4c209f4353):

> I think Options => Advanced => Printouts => Insert long printouts on multiple pages.

Works a charm, just have to specify when a pop-up comes up that you want it on a single page.